# Cocos2d app EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, not show what bt shows

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing an app and I'm racking my brain trying to figure out why it keeps crashing. I think it is to do with a timer, but I'm unsure what the bt code means. If anyone can help I will be very grateful.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x01e3f051 libobjc.A.dylib`_cache_getImp + 9, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xd0000008)
frame #0: 0x01e3f051 libobjc.A.dylib`_cache_getImp + 9
frame #1: 0x01e2cac4 libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpMethod + 42
frame #2: 0x01e2ca88 libobjc.A.dylib`class_respondsToSelector + 65
frame #3: 0x0213b0d3 CoreFoundation`objectIsKindOfClass + 51
frame #4: 0x021c4087 CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 71
frame #5: 0x01e2e0b9 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 86
frame #6: 0x01f4ca65 libc++abi.dylib`safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 13
frame #7: 0x01f4cacd libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 23
frame #8: 0x01f4dc4e libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 83
frame #9: 0x01e2dfbd libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 47
frame #10: 0x020e0f98 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 360
frame #11: 0x020e0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #12: 0x02e427e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
frame #13: 0x02e42668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #14: 0x00a5f4fc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
frame #15: 0x000f75af Carnivale`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3a4) + 127 at main.m:14
frame #16: 0x00002ba5 Carnivale`start + 53
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly accessing a released object.  You could try turning on NSZombiesEnabled:

> In Xcode 4.x press
>
> alt-command-R
>
> select the "Diagnostics" tab and click "Enable Zombie Objects":

This turns released objects into NSZombie instances that print console warnings when used again. This is a debugging aid that increases memory use (no object is really released) but improves error reporting.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, looks like you were right. I'm now getting termination due to uncaught exception error, on _NSZombie_NSException. Is there a way to help track down which object this is?

Comment: Managed to sort it out. Put an NSLog in each timer and displayed all the info from each timer. Turns out I was trying to access an array element that was not there.